# Catching "chip close" event vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js

I'm relatively new in the vuetify world and, during my first web app development I'm struggling a lot with event handling.
In this case I'm writing a "UserPicker" component using the VAutocomplete one.

The component works by sending an async request to a server that responds with a list of accounts matching the user input.

The result should be pretty similiar to the example here:
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/autocompletes/#slots

Everything seems to work fine, except I haven't found a way to catch the event in the subject of this question.

This is the code I've written:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, watch } from "vue";
import { useServerRequestsStore } from "@/stores/server-requests";
const input = ref();
const items = ref<Array<UserPreview>>([]);
const select = ref<Array<UserPreview>>([]);
const selectSet = new Set();
const search = ref("");
const serverRequests = useServerRequestsStore();

interface UserPreview {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  username: string;
  avatar: string;
}

function addUser(userItem: UserPreview) {
  try {
    selectSet.add(userItem.username);
    select.value.push(userItem);
    items.value = [];
    search.value = "";
    input.value.focus();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
function removeUser(userItem: UserPreview) {
  selectSet.delete(userItem.username);
  const toRemove = select.value.findIndex(
    (added) => added.username == userItem.username
  );
  console.log("removing " + userItem.username + " at index " + toRemove);
  select.value.splice(toRemove, 1);
  console.log("after removal:", select.value);
}

watch(search, async (val) => {
  if (val.length == 0) return;
  try {
    const users = await serverRequests.getUserByUsername(val, false);
    items.value = users
      .filter((user: any) => !selectSet.has(user.userInfo.username))
      .map((user: any) => ({
        firstName: user.userInfo.firstName,
        lastName: user.userInfo.lastName,
        username: user.userInfo.username,
        title: user.userInfo.username, //richiesto per far comparire automaticamente i suggerimenti
        avatar: user.userInfo.profilePicture,
      }));
  } catch (error) {
    items.value = [];
  }
});
</script>
<template>
  <VAutocomplete
    @keydown.enter.prevent
    ref="input"
    v-model="select"
    v-model:search="search"
    :items="items"
    class="mx-4"
    density="compact"
    hide-no-data
    hide-details
    label="Seleziona destinatari"
    style="max-width: 300px"
    chips
    closable-chips
    multiple
  >
    <template v-slot:item="{ item }"
      ><VListItem class="text-center" @click="addUser(item.raw)">
        <VAvatar size="40px" color="black" variant="outlined"
          ><VImg alt="profile avatar" :src="item.raw.avatar" />
        </VAvatar>
        <VListItemTitle
          >{{ item.raw.firstName }} {{ item.raw.lastName }}</VListItemTitle
        >
        <VListItemSubtitle>{{ item.raw.username }}</VListItemSubtitle>
      </VListItem>
    </template>
    <template v-slot:chip="{ item }">
      <VChip
        @click:close="removeUser(item.raw)"
        :text="item.raw.username"
      ></VChip>
    </template>
  </VAutocomplete>
</template>
```

As you can see in the bottom of the template, where the VChip component is used, I'm able to correctly handle the @click:close event, however the VChip, at least in this context, can also be closed by selecting them with the arrow key and pressing backspace while editing the VAutocomplete input.

I've tried playing around with the various @vnode-before-unmount, @keydown.backspace and     @update:model-value events but none of them did the trick.
A particular detail to notice is that @vnode-before-unmount, unlike the other 2 events, actually gets triggered correctly, and correctly calls the removeUser function, however, for some reason, the scope of the component is not carried on to the procedure, in fact the select reference is empty when the handler is called via this event, while it's correctly populated when the user triggers the @click:close one.

Thanks in advance for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution on github, I hope it helps someone who has encountered this problem too, i just changed the `@click.stop` to `@click.close`: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/16740